# Change Parent Status/Class Based on child status angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to change the class of parent if all the child has a status of "fail" i am using angular 5.

MY JSON :

```
[{"parent":"PARENT 1", "child":[{ "name":"Child 1", "status":"fail" }, { "name":"Child 1", "status":"fail" },{ "name":"Child 1", "status":"fail" }, { "name":"Child 1", "status":"fail" }], "someVal":"SOME VALUE" }, { "parent":"PARENT 2", "child":[{ "name":"Child 1", "status":"pass" }, { "name":"Child 1", "status":"pass" },{ "name":"Child 1", "status":"fail" }, { "name":"Child 1", "status":"fail" }], "someVal":"SOME VALUE" }, { "parent":"PARENT 3", "child":[{ "name":"Child 1", "status":"pass" }, { "name":"Child 1", "status":"pass" },{ "name":"Child 1", "status":"pass" }, { "name":"Child 1", "status":"pass" }], "someVal":"SOME VALUE" }]
```

my HTML :

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let anyvar of mainJSONOBJ" [ngClass]="FAIL/PASS"><a href="">{{anyvar.parent}}</a> 
    <ul *ngFor="let anyvar1 of anyvar.child" >
        <li *ngIf="anyvar1.child"><a href="#">{{anyvar.child.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

What I am trying to do is Change the "ngClass" to "FAIL" if all the child has "status" as "fail" else "ngClass" to "PASS" in the parent LI.

Is there a way I can do that with angular 5. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `BehaviorSubject` to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

```
[ngClass]="isFailed(anyvar) ? 'fail' : 'pass'"
```

```js
isFailed(value: { child: [{ status: string }] }): boolean {
    return value.child.every(c => c.status === 'fail');
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lkuthv

Comment: I am getting this error dont know why :
`Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 25 in`

Comment: @KakuSarmah indeed. Edited.